# Doubt in recently upvote

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, top-users

When I log today morning there was only -1 reputation in my **recent achievement**.

But after i came and log in to my pc.

then I got **69** reputation,

[image]

In past I get message from moderators about voting some thing(Can't remember)

**Is there any way to check upvoted user??**

Comment: Voting is anonymous, even mods can't see who voted. Those votes will be detected by the fraud script that runs at 03:00 UTC and reversed.

Comment: so finally i get message about something like fraud upvote or some thing !!!

Answer (score 4):

In short, if you haven't done anything wrong, you haven't got anything to worry about.

We have enough tools at our disposal (with the help of the Community Team), to be able to differentiate between you creating sock puppets to inflate your reputation, and you being the (un)fortunate victim of a random user deciding to vote for your posts.

These things happen; don't worry about it.

Comment: So are you sure if user removed il not get any time period to come back again??

Comment: im bother about my **Voting rights in Stack site**

Comment: @Abdulla: if you haven't done anything wrong, you won't be banned... like I said, don't worry about it.

Comment: already I got banned, Without doing nothing. That's why

Comment: For the record: I've handled a few sock accounts that do not appear to be related to Abdulla but had spread their voting beyond their puppet master account. Abdulla lost 9 votes because of this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can u explain more. Please be kind. I realy cant underatnd your above comment

Comment: @Abdulla: while looking into the voting on your account I found some fake accounts. Those accounts did not appear to be yours. I deleted the accounts and the votes they cast were invalidated. 9 of those votes had gone to your posts.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks once again for your activity