# Top Tag Calculation Error

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, top-users

In my Stack Site ([Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla?tab=profile)) tab you can check my top tags(Image attach below)

[image: 01]

But if i calculate my tag using [How many upvotes do I have for each tag?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag)
 it show me the correct number. (I check with some other users, its same)

Can check below image

[image]

You can clearly see in my `PHP` tag upvote count.

> Whats wrong with Stack Site??

**EDIT 01(2015/08/07)**

I Provide answers in this couple of days(at least 10+), You can check this(below image) and understand nothing happening.

> **Note:** Skip `Score Count`, check `post count`. Atleaset that should be increase. But its also same

[image: 01]

And **this is a [Mathias R. Jessen](https://serverfault.com/users/105072/mathias-r-jessen) comment of my post**

[image]

**Edit 02(2015/08/09)**

Four day has passed. Tag count is same !!

Comment: The data explorer is only updated once a week. So it will lag behind the real-time data.

Comment: @Mysticial But its work perfect early. This couple of days only this happen

Comment: You probably haven't had any votes in PHP for a few days. I also see a -80 removal event. I'm not gonna guess what happened, but it could be that a user who upvoted 8 of your PHP answers got deleted - thereby dropping your score from 102 to 94. And the data explorer hasn't updated yet.

Comment: I already inform that to moderators [doubt-in-recently-upvote](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300669/doubt-in-recently-upvote). And Yesterday and 2days before i earned points.

Comment: I've seen the same thing for the past couple of days. Individual tag scores and (incidentally) Top Users pages have remained the same since monday (noticed this for [tag:powershell] but seems to be the same for other tags)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oopz one man there understood problem

Comment: @Abdulla if you click the tag you'll see a search page (currently) listing **286** php-tagged posts as opposed to the **258** posts listed on your profile (I doubt you posted 28 php answers in the last 13 hours). Update your answer with a screenshot from the search page to illustrate the divergence

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you study me well. I informed morerators but they are telling that site is correct. Im so confuced. I thought this only happen to me.

Comment: I didnt get your last line in previous comment

Comment: There is known issue with the tag calculation script. Not with the script itself but with the job that should start it every day. That job is not running, hence no change in tag counts...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That query is not correctly designed to calculate your tag score.

1. It only looks at upvotes, whereas the tag score is your number of upvotes *minus* your number of downvotes.
2. It looks at all posts, whereas your tag score is only for *answers* given in that tag.
3. It doesn't consider community wiki posts, which do not count towards your tag score.

While the Data Explorer data *is* only updated once a week and that can sometimes make the data out-of-sync, that data you are looking at does not correspond to the same calculations that contribute to your tag score.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I Score on `PHP` tag. But past couple of days its not changing. Please Kindly check my [Reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla?tab=reputation) cahnge

Comment: As far as I can tell, your tag score is currently correct. It matches the vote counts on all of your posts.

Comment: Plz ckeck @MathiasR.Jessen comment on my question

Comment: @Abdulla: Better use this query for tag-scores: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/345340/tag-scores?UserId=4595675