# Tag scores and Top Users pages not updating since monday

Tags: bug, tags, tag-score

I noticed on Wednesday that the Top Users page for [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) seemed to show the exact same results as the two previous days.

Seemingly related, individual tag scores have also frozen:

[image]

But click the tag and there is a difference of 18 posts:

[image]

My impression was that tag scores are recalculated at <s>00:00</s> 03:00 UTC every day, and I have **not** posted 18 powershell-tagged posts in the last 11 hours

This issue was [raised by another user on wednesday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300806/712649) but got mistaken/dismissed as a complaint about data explorer (which is not really the case, just a symptom).

Comment: Yup, I'd noticed it too. This keeps happening from time to time, we'll just have to wait. Also see [Can I haz stinkin' silver tag badge, plz?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253587)

Comment: Given all caching and consistency problems lately: did SO switch to a MongoDB backend or something? :P

Comment: I usually notice they update around 03:00 UTC.. though not since Monday or so.

Comment: I was actually *about* to ask this question (like, within 10 minutes)... I want my Java bronze badge already!

Comment: This is an evergreen problem, see [the duplicate posts on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run).

Comment: @BrockAdams Yeah I noticed. I'll post an answer and close once it's eventually fixed. This time around though, it seems to affact SO only, (e.g. my tag scores of SF are up to date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem seems to have been fixed now, Tag scores are up to date

Comment: I still have this problem. My `python` tag score is stuck for a pretty while on `97`. However, in the mobile app it shows `138`.

Comment: @bagrat Looks to be a recurring problem, last time it took 3-4 days to catch up

Comment: thanks for the reply  Mathias. My issue seems to persist for months :(